# Get results of parent when searched in child for nested document in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-nested

I have projects, and in each project I have tasks, and in each task I have comments. So it looks like:

```
-> Projects
    -> Tasks
        -> Comments
```

I have used nested documents to store the data in the index in Elastic search. My structure looks like this:

```
PUT projects/
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "proj_number": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },      
        "proj_name": {
        "type": "text"
     },
     "tasks": {
         "type": "nested",
         "properties": {
         "proj_nam_id": {
             "type": "integer"
         },
         "task_name": {
             "type": "text"
         },
         "proj_tas_id": {
            "type": "integer"
         },
         "comments": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "proj_com_id": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "message": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "task_id": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "proj_nam_id": {
                "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I have a task page where I show all tasks of all projects, and there I want to add a search, where if user searches anything and if that searched text is present in task name, or in its comments, then I need to show only those tasks.

So I want that if something is searched from the child then I get its parent's (only those tasks which have searched comments or if its in task name). One more thing that I want is that  I have one more page of projects, and there too I need to show all projects and need to add a search box, there if user searches anything, I need to search in projects, tasks and comments, and need to display project in which its task or comment is found. I have tried using inner_hits, and following is my query:

```
GET projects/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "tasks",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": [
                                {
                                    "must": [
                                        {
                                            "bool": {
                                                "should": [
                                                    {
                                                        "multi_match": {
                                                            "query": "task",
                                                            "lenient": "true",
                                                            "fields": [
                                                                "tasks.task_name"
                                                            ],
                                                            "type": "best_fields",
                                                            "operator": "and"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "inner_hits": {
                            "size": 100
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "tasks.comments",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "should": [
                                                {
                                                    "multi_match": {
                                                        "query": "task",
                                                        "lenient": "true",
                                                        "fields": [
                                                            "tasks.comments.message"
                                                        ],
                                                        "type": "best_fields",
                                                        "operator": "and"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "inner_hits": {
                            "size": 100
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But here I have issues:

1. I am not getting results as I want, in the inner_hits, I am getting searched comments, and in doc result, I am getting all the tasks, so I will have to filter the tasks (as I want tasks) using task_id from comments. Is there a good way to do it, as I don't think this method is good to proceed.
2. We cannot get more than 150 records for inner_hits, as that is its maximum limit.

Please let me know how should I do it.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried dumping all the content into some field on the parent object? At least this might work for tasks: there are rarely many comments for a task. For projects it's the other way around: usually people have few projects and many tasks in each so you'd probably want to have tasks index with `project_id` on each task and use `terms` aggregation to retrieve those for projects page.